# Creating XLS with JasperReports API, an existing jrxml file, and an existing JDBC connection

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a jrxml *iReport* template completed. It looks find when I used the *NetBeans* plugin to "preview" it. However, I am having a lot of trouble getting it generated through Java code.

Here's what I tried:

```
String fileName = [path to the .jasper file]
String outFileName = "test.xls";
HashMap hm = new HashMap();

// Getting datasource
String query = [some query];
ResultSet rset = [some DB scripts that executes the query];
JRResultSetDataSource jasperReports = new JRResultSetDataSource(rset);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, hm, jasperReports);

// Create a XLS exporter
JRExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();

// Export the thing
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, outFileName);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Anyway... this is what I did and it returns an empty *xls* file. What am I missing? Given that *iReport* has this entire suite in *NetBeans* to make *JR* reports, I'd imagine there's some easy way to just call those template files and export any data file I want.

I Googled around a lot but had yet to find a working solution.

Note: The *ResultSet* works 100%, so it's the *JR*-part of the code I am having issues.

Comment: Are you sure there are results in the result set? When you say it works when you do the preview, is this with an empty data set, or something else? What do you mean by empty also? Do you still get the headers and all, or completely blank? My guess is that the result has no results and the report property `When No Data` is to to `No Pages`. Thus empty excel file.

Comment: No, preview gives a table with the desired data. Empty excel file = nothing in file.

Comment: Did you check the report property I mentioned? Did you check that there are results in the ResultSet?

Comment: Did you figure this one out yet?

Comment: I haven't gotten back to this yet. On a 12+ hour crunch (boss suddenly pushed up the deadline plus there were technical issues with company equipment)

Comment: Ha, been there before. Good luck!

Comment: Anyway, I managed to create a pdf with charts from some copied code found somewhere. I will post that up for other people with the same issue on Monday. It's not XLS, but I am sure it's not hard to improvise from there.